# Strange SUM() result

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a strange problem with mysql sum() result.

```
SELECT  `users_limits`.times, SUM( l.times ) AS  `result` 
    FROM  `users_limits` 
      INNER JOIN  `users_limits` AS  `l` 
      INNER JOIN  `vacation_types` AS  `v` ON l.id_vacation_type = v.id_vacation_type
   WHERE  l.year =2014 AND v.type =0
```

This query give me result:
times = 10;
result = 30;

But should give me result 10 too, because I have only one record in my db, with these conditions.

Comment: would you mind sharing your tables and data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What's the point of joining `users_limits` to itself, with no join condition? What do you expect to get from a query that has an aggregate function with no `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Looks like you missing `GROUP BY` in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need GROUP BY . try add this

```
 GROUP BY  l.times
```

like that

```
   WHERE l.year =2014 AND v.type =0
   GROUP BY  l.times
```

EDIT-:

```
  SELECT  `users_limits`.times, SUM( l.times ) AS  `result` 
  FROM  `users_limits` l
  INNER JOIN  `vacation_types` AS  `v` ON l.id_vacation_type = v.id_vacation_type
  WHERE l.year =2014 AND v.type =0
  GROUP BY  l.times
```

Comment: Count gimme result = 1; I want to count content of time columns.

Comment: I guess thats not the case as OP says there is only one record but by using joins OP is getting the cross product so the result is 3 time as he expected

Comment: Probably you are right. Count return me 3 and it works good when I delete join. Why? How can I repair it?